# Obtener ulimo registro de una lista vb.net

Tags: lista, vb

Hola a todos tengo una variable de Tipo List (of ) en donde tengo guardado el id, codigo, nombre , etc de una lista de clientes. Lo que necesito es obtener el ultimo id de toda la lista...puedo hacerlo con for each pero prefiero una forma en donde ubique la ultima fila (por el campo id) de manera directa

Answer (score 1):

Haz algo como esto:

```
' Crea un array vacío.
Dim frutas() As String = {}

' Obtiene el último elemento del array, o bien,
' un valor por defecto (probablemente null)
' si el arreglo está vacío
Dim ultimo As String = frutas.LastOrDefault()

' Mostrar el resultado.
MsgBox(IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ultimo),
       "<string vacío o nulo>",
       ultimo))

' El código produce la siguiente salira:
'
' <string vacío o nulo>
```

[Está en la documentación de referencia de .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301849(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo asi:

```
Dim lst As New List(Of T) 
...
...
If lst.Count > 0 Then
 Dim lastItem = lst(lst.Count - 1)
End If
```

Para buscar un item por un id especifico,deberias usar Linq

```
Dim itm = lst.FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.Id = varId)
```